# C# webbrowser javascript

Tags: c#

I am trying to display a website through my C# Application using the fellow code:

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.barbiecoupons.gr");
```

The but the website's javascript is not working.

What do I need it to do?

Comment: Set `webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = false` and check what errors are being produced, perhaps? You need to give more information than just "It isn't working".

Comment: google [enable javascript webbrowser  winform](https://www.google.de/search?q=enable+javascript+webbrowser+c%23&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=L0q3VeSEK8bNygOEm5jwBA#q=enable+javascript+webbrowser++winform)